# Clojurescript/Reagent Unit testing component output and behaviour

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, clojurescript, jestjs, reagent

We used react for about one year now, with immutable data, very impressive. We now want to move to Clojurescript/Reagent, but we need a very good way to test our code. For components this is what we did:

1. Test the output of the component, depending on the props we sent:
2. Test that the component invokes the right functions and with the right parameters when an event like click occurs

For 1 it would be like:

```
function renderFFC(filters, search_criterias)
{
    return TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(FilterIntervalNumberComponent,{filter:filters, search_criteria:search_criterias}));
}

describe("IN", function(){
    it("should render search criteria - interval", function() {
        var criterias = {};
        var ffc = renderFFC(filter, criterias);
        expect(ffc.refs[0].getDOMNode().value).toBeNull();
        expect(ffc.refs[1].getDOMNode().value).toBeNull();
     });
```

For 2 it would be something like:

```
describe("OUT", function(){
    it("should change the values, then click - boolean ", function() {
        //mock function
        set_criteria_and_search = jest.genMockFunction();

        var fbc = renderFBC(filter, {});

        React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.change(fbc.refs.yes.getDOMNode(),{nativeEvent: {target: {value: true}}});

        expect(controller.set_criteria_and_search.mock.calls)
          .toEqual(
                    [['taxes_applied',{'taxes_applied':[{value:"1"}]}]]
                );
     });
```

We used facebook Jest for the tests.

How do I dothe same thing in Clojurescript with Reagent, preferably having the tests automatically run?

Comment: Looking forward to an answer. Try with the lein template **reagent** and see what they set up. Don't forget the `+test` option https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-template/blob/master/README.md#options

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get +test to work.

lein new figwheel name -- --reagent +test??

Comment: That's the figwheel template you are using. Use the reagent template instead: `lein new reagent <name> +test`

Comment: I managed to make figwheel run my tests automatically, in a second tab. I don't have any component tests yet, and I am studying differeny scenarios on how to do that. For figwheel tests I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-kj2qwJa_E then took the inspiration on how to change the configuration from the sample app: https://github.com/bhauman/crashverse

Comment: Nice! Could you post yourself an answer with the snippet of configuration from the project.clj? That would be helpful for people coming to the question in the future!

Comment: Configure testing in a figwheel/reagent proj:

1. Addi the test build in  project.cljs

https://github.com/DanBunea/cljs-learning-weather-app/blob/master/project.clj

See the :cljsbuild  test and :aliases

2. Adding a test.html in resources/public

https://github.com/DanBunea/cljs-learning-weather-app/blob/master/resources/public/test.html

3. Adding the test-runner and the core.cljs

https://github.com/DanBunea/cljs-learning-weather-app/tree/master/test/weather_app

4. starting both autobuild:

lein figwheel dev test 

2 tabs in a browser: localhost:3449/index.html & localhost:3449/test.html

Comment: Or look here: https://github.com/DanBunea/cljs-learning-weather-app/wiki/Configure-testing

Comment: There is a very active slack community in clojure.  You'll get a lot of answers over there.  Not nearly as many here:  http://clojurians.net/

Comment: Thanks Mike I am already in. I need to answer all my questions because now I found the answers :) maybe some others will find them useful

Comment: I also posted a way in which we started to test components, in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368653/clojurescript-reagent-unit-testing-component-simulate-onchange. Basically render them on screen, and check the rendered dom elements using jquery as well as simulating events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing reagent components:

**Test the component output. For a component:**

```
 (defn weather-component [city temp country]
  [:div#weather
    [:h2#city {:on-click #(do-something 101)} city ]
    [:h3#temp temp]
    [:h3#contry country]])
```

The test:

```
 (deftest weather-component-test-in
  ;;WHEN render component in test
  (let [comp (r/render-component [w/weather-component "Paris" 12]
                             (. js/document (getElementById "test")))]
    ;;ASSERT
    (is (= (d/html (sel1 :#city)) "Paris"))
    (is (= (d/html (sel1 :#temp)) "12"))))
```

**Test that the component invokes the right functions and with the right parameters when an event like click occurs**

```
(deftest weather-component-test-out 
 (let [comp (r/render-component [w/weather-component "London" 0]
                             (. js/document (getElementById "test"))) 
    expected-invocations (atom [])] 
    (with-redefs [weather-app.core/do-something #(swap! expected-invocations conj %)] 
      (sim/click (sel1 :#city) {})
      (is (=[101] @expected-invocations)))))
```

To manipulate the dom and simulate events:

[cljs-react-test "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT"] and dommy (d/...)